# Fastest way to multiply large numbers in python?

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, multiplication

Take a look at the following code:

```
total = 0
for j in range(int(start)-1,int(end)):
    total += (A+j)*(B+j)*(C+j)*(D+j)
print(total%1000000007)
```

Now the code is working fine but I need to reduce the time complexity.

1<=A,B,C,D<=10^5

1<=start<=end<=10^5

As you can see the numbers can be very large.
How can I speed up the multiplication part?
I tried Russian Peasant technique. It is still not fast enough.

Also I read similar posts on python multiplication but it couldn't solve my issue.

Comment: [karatsuba's multiplication algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm)?

Comment: recursion limit exceeds

Comment: You can increase the recursion depth by doing this (note that 2000 is just an example): `import sys` `sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)`

Comment: I did that but it is still not fast enough...time limit still exceeds

Comment: Have you tried this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiply-large-numbers-represented-as-strings/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use modular arithmetic here.

```
(a+b)%c=(a%c+b%c)%c

(a∗b)%c=((a%c)∗(b%c))%c

(a−b)%c=((a%c)−(b%c)+c)%c

(a/b)%c=((a%c)∗(b−1%c))%c
```

This will ensure integer overflow as well as keep time complexity in check.

Answer (score 0):

I think for this, it would be enough to remember that `(a+b)%c = a%c +b%c`

Since each part of the loop isn't very big you can try:

```
total = 0
for j in range(int(start)-1,int(end)):
    total = (total + (A+j)*(B+j)*(C+j)*(D+j)) %1000000007
print(total)
```